# how can i make an image file downloadable from apache server using php?

Tags: php, apache, file, server, download

I don't know if this has been asked before, please pardon in advance.

I created an image compression web app using the tinyPNG API, and it works as intended - that is users can upload an image file and it is compressed and saved in the server.

But then I create a download functionality for the user to download/save the compressed image.

On clicking the download link it throws up an error:

> can’t find the file at http://localhost/var/www/html/imgtest/uploads/67403938_10219921906785196_7063388762713096192_n_1574687362.jpg.

Even though the compressed image is in the server.

Please help!!!

MY CODE:

````
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");

//makes PHP execute faster
set_time_limit(0);

//API key
\Tinify\setKey("API_KEY_HERE");

//Main code
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    //supported image formats.
    $supported_image = array('image/jpg', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png');

    foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key=>$val){

        $file_name = $_FILES['images']['name'][$key];

        // get file extension
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        // get filename without extension
        $filenamewithoutextension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

        if (in_array($_FILES['images']['type'][$key], $supported_image)) {

            if (!file_exists(getcwd(). '/uploads')) {

                $oldmask = umask(0);

                mkdir(getcwd(). '/uploads', 0777, true);

                umask($oldmask);
            }

            $filename_to_store = $filenamewithoutextension. '_' .time(). '.' .$ext;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key], getcwd(). '/uploads/' .$filename_to_store);


            $compress_file = getcwd(). '/uploads/' .$filename_to_store;

            // optimize image using TinyPNG
            try {
                $source = \Tinify\fromFile(getcwd(). '/uploads/' .$filename_to_store);
                $source->toFile(getcwd(). '/uploads/' .$filename_to_store);

                //The code to show a modal for downloading the converted file.


            } catch(Exception $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<a href=".$compress_file." download>Download</a>";
}

?>```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is, that you create the link with `$compress_file` that contains absolute path to the file.

> /var/www/html/imgtest/uploads/67403938_10219921906785196_7063388762713096192_n_1574687362.jpg

So when the link is clickend and the url is resolved in browser the result is

> http://localhost/var/www/html/imgtest/uploads/67403938_10219921906785196_7063388762713096192_n_1574687362.jpg.

So if the localhost domain is pointed to `/var/www/html/imgtest/` than the server is looking for the file in this path which doesn't exist:

> /var/www/html/imgtest/var/www/html/imgtest/uploads/...

When you are generating the path to the compressed file you should put it's url into other variable where you wouldn't prepend the current directory.

```php
$compress_file_url = '/uploads/' .$filename_to_store;
$compress_file = getcwd(). $compress_file_url;
```

Then you should use the `$compress_file_url` instead of `$compress_file` when creating a link

```php
echo "<a href=\"$compress_file_url\" download>Download</a>";
```

This should work assuming your localhost domain is pointed to `/var/www/html/imgtest`. If your localhost domain is pointed to `/var/www/html` you might need to prepend `$compress_file_url` with `/imgtest` before it's used to create a link.

```php
$compress_file_url = '/uploads/' .$filename_to_store;
$compress_file = getcwd(). $compress_file_url;
$compress_file_url = '/imgtest' . $compress_file_url;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked: I used the `$compress_file_url = '/imgtest' . $compress_file_url;` instead. Thanks once again for your prompt help.